# Is it possible to use the same app multiple times on the same page with VueJS?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an project where I retrieve data from my backend and show it on the frontend using vue.js, I need to use the same app multiple times OR use an app in an app.

Here's an example, https://jsfiddle.net/Lsc7hggs/4/ :

```
<!-- app in app -->
<div class="colorHandler">
    <div class="nameHandler">
         <p>[% nameAttr() %]</p>
         <p>[% nameAttr() %]</p>
         <p>[% randomColor() %]</p>
         <p>[% randomColor() %]</p>
    </div>
</div>

<hr> <!-- OR -->

<!-- multiple time the same app -->
<div class="nameHandler">
  <p>[% nameAttr() %]</p>
</div>

<div class="nameHandler">
  <p>[% nameAttr() %]</p>
</div>

<div class="colorHandler">
<p>[% randomColor() %]</p>
</div>

<div class="colorHandler">
<p>[% randomColor() %]</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make this work ?

Comment: Could you achieve the results you want using components? One Vue and then multiple copies of a component within the Vue?

Comment: @admcfajn I agree this could also be done with components.

Comment: @admcfajn Yes as long as I can use multiple time the different Vue next to each other

Comment: Passing variables between components can get a little hairy, have a look at this, it uses more than one Vue to let different components 'talk' to each other: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to have nested Vues.

You *can* create multiple Vues.

```
const colorHandlers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".colorHandler"))
for (let handler of colorHandlers){
  new Vue({
    el: handler,
    methods:{
      randomColor:function(){
        var colors = "['#e6f0ff', '#000a1a' ,'#ffe680', '#ffcc00', '#ffd9b3']";
        var parsed_colors = colors.match(/#[a-f0-9]{6}/g);
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * parsed_colors.length); 
        var randomElement = parsed_colors[randomIndex];
        return randomElement
      }
    },
    delimiters: ["[%","%]"]
  });
}

const nameHandlers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".nameHandler"))
for (let handler of nameHandlers) {
  new Vue({
    el: handler, 
    methods:{
      nameAttr:function(){
        var nom_prenom = 'John Doe';
        return nom_prenom
      }
    },
    delimiters: ["[%","%]"]
  });
}
```

Your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsc7hggs/6/).

But you could also do this.

```
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    methods:{
    randomColor:function(){
        var colors = "['#e6f0ff', '#000a1a' ,'#ffe680', '#ffcc00', '#ffd9b3']";
        var parsed_colors = colors.match(/#[a-f0-9]{6}/g);
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * parsed_colors.length); 
        var randomElement = parsed_colors[randomIndex];
        return randomElement
    },
    nameAttr:function(){
      var nom_prenom = 'John Doe';
      return nom_prenom
    }
  },
  delimiters: ["[%","%]"]
})
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsc7hggs/8/).

Comment: The second proposition is the best one, but the first is interesting for another use case so let it there :)

Comment: @lindow generally, I try to answer the specific question and then see if I can offer a better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote a small package based off Bert's answer. It allows the Syntax:

```
import MultiVue from 'vue-multivue';
import AwesomeComponent from './Components/AwesomeComponent.vue';

new MultiVue('.my-app', {
   components: {
       AwesomeComponent
   }
});
```

The package is here: https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-multivue